# tidymodels - predict() and fit() giving different model performance results when applied to the same dataset

Tags: r, random-forest, tidymodels, r-parsnip

Currently using the `tidymodels` framework and struggling to understand some differences in model predictions and performance results I get, specifically when I use both `fit` and `predict` on the exact same dataset (i.e. the dataset the model was trained on).

Below's a reproducible example - I'm using the cells dataset and training a random-forest on the data (`rf_fit`). The object `rf_fit$fit$predictions` is one of the sets of predictions I assess the accuracy of. I then use `rf_fit` to make predictions on the same data via the `predict` function (yielding `rf_training_pred`, the other set of predictions I assess the accuracy of).

**My question is - why are these sets of predictions different from each other? And why are they so different?**

I presume something must be going on under the hood I'm not aware off, but I'd expected these to be identical, as I'd assumed that `fit()` trained a model (and has some predictions associated with this trained model) and then `predict()` takes that exact model and just re-applies it to (in this case) the same data - hence the predictions of both should be identical.

What am I missing? Any suggestions or help in understanding would be hugely appreciated - thanks in advance!

```r
# Load required libraries 
library(tidymodels); library(modeldata) 
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip

# Set seed 
set.seed(123)

# Split up data into training and test
data(cells, package = "modeldata")

# Define Model
rf_mod <- rand_forest(trees = 1000) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

# Fit the model to training data and then predict on same training data
rf_fit <- rf_mod %>% 
  fit(class ~ ., data = cells)
rf_training_pred <- rf_fit %>%
  predict(cells, type = "prob")

# Evaluate accuracy 
data.frame(rf_fit$fit$predictions) %>%
  bind_cols(cells %>% select(class)) %>%
  roc_auc(truth = class, PS)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 roc_auc binary         0.903

rf_training_pred %>%   
  bind_cols(cells %>% select(class)) %>%
  roc_auc(truth = class, .pred_PS)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 roc_auc binary          1.00
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, look at the documentation for what `ranger::ranger()` returns, especially what `predictions` is:

> Predicted classes/values, based on out of bag samples (classification and regression only).

This isn't the same as what you get when predicting on the final whole fitted model.

Second, when you do predict on the final model, you get the same thing whether you predict on the tidymodels object or the underlying ranger object.

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
library(modeldata) 

data(cells, package = "modeldata")

cells <- cells %>% select(-case)

# Define Model
rf_mod <- rand_forest(trees = 1000) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

# Fit the model to training data and then predict on same training data
rf_fit <- rf_mod %>% 
  fit(class ~ ., data = cells)

tidymodels_results <- predict(rf_fit, cells, type = "prob")
tidymodels_results
#> # A tibble: 2,019 × 2
#>    .pred_PS .pred_WS
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1   0.929    0.0706
#>  2   0.764    0.236 
#>  3   0.222    0.778 
#>  4   0.920    0.0796
#>  5   0.961    0.0386
#>  6   0.0486   0.951 
#>  7   0.101    0.899 
#>  8   0.954    0.0462
#>  9   0.293    0.707 
#> 10   0.405    0.595 
#> # … with 2,009 more rows

ranger_results <- predict(rf_fit$fit, cells, type = "response")
as_tibble(ranger_results$predictions)
#> # A tibble: 2,019 × 2
#>        PS     WS
#>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 0.929  0.0706
#>  2 0.764  0.236 
#>  3 0.222  0.778 
#>  4 0.920  0.0796
#>  5 0.961  0.0386
#>  6 0.0486 0.951 
#>  7 0.101  0.899 
#>  8 0.954  0.0462
#>  9 0.293  0.707 
#> 10 0.405  0.595 
#> # … with 2,009 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**NOTE:** this only works because we have used very simple preprocessing. As [we note here](https://www.tmwr.org/models.html#use-the-model-results) you generally should *not* predict on the underlying `$fit` object.

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification, that makes complete sense :)